# How to solve Null Pointer Exception inside of Repository function while returning from function?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, nullpointerexception, viewmodel

View model File code:

```
    fun retrive(doc_name : String,uid: String){
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
         bitmap.value = repository.retrive(doc_name,uid)!!

    }
 }
```

The below code is the code of My repository Implementation

```
    override suspend fun retrive(doc_name:String,uid: String)  : Bitmap{
     var bitmap :Bitmap? = null


    val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference?.child("/image/0XhL4jD4XCemk38rcRkIEjJMgjh2/Aadhar")
    val localfile = createTempFile("tempImage", null)
    if (storageRef.getFile(localfile).isSuccessful) {

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localfile.absolutePath)
        Log.d("Check","$bitmap")

                       }
         return bitmap!!

     }
```

So this function is going to Firebase Storage and retrieving the image and storing it into a file and than converting it into a bitmap.
I am trying to return the bitmap from Repository so I can use it in UI as the project is following MVVM architecture
But as soon as I run it displays the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.example.adminv1, PID: 23030
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.alliaise_adminv1.Admin.Admin_Verif_rp_imp.retrive(Admin_Verif_rp_imp.kt:70)
    at com.example.alliaise_adminv1.Admin.Admin_Verif_VM$retrive$1.invokeSuspend(Admin_Verif_VM.kt:30)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
```

So the error is in 2 places , the first is in Admin repository implementation File as shows in error line 70 and the same in  Admin View model file as shown in error Line number 30

The error lines are :

1. In repository

   ```
     return bitmap!!
   ```
2. In View Model:

   ```
   bitmap.value = repository.retrive(doc_name,uid)!!
   ```

I am not sure what is going wrong but I have got a feeling stating the image is falling to get Retrieved from Firebase . I have cross checked all the paths. I think there is some issue in generating a temp file as that can be the only issue not sure tbh. Kindly help please

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `!!` , using `!!` means you tell the compiler that this method will return something (`non-null`) and if it is return `null` it will throw an `Exception` at runtime.

Only use `!!` when you are sure that you will return `non-null` data.

In your case, the data from storage are `nullable` , so use `?` instead.

```kotlin
override suspend fun retrive(doc_name:String,uid: String)  : Bitmap? //add ? 
{
...
//remove `!!`
return bitmap
}

// also here remove "!!", and change your bitmap data type to Bitmap?
bitmap.value = repository.retrive(doc_name,uid)
```

If your receiver method required `non-null` bitmap, you could use `if else` statement, although loading a `nullable` bitmap to `imageView` is actually safe.